# SwiftUI Login Page Layout

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5

I am exploring SwiftUI as I am trying to build a login view and now I am facing a problem

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: What I already achieved]

As you can see I already reached this point but I don't like my implementation

```
struct ContentView : View {
@State var username: String = ""
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Login")
            .font(.title)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .lineLimit(nil)
            Text("Please")
                .font(.subheadline)

        HStack {
            VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                Text("Username: ")
                Text("Password: ")

            }
            VStack {
                TextField($username, placeholder: Text("type something here..."))
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                TextField($username, placeholder: Text("type something here..."))
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Because in order to make the username and password text aligned exactly in the middle of the textfield, I had to put literal spacing value of `20` in the `VStack` which I don't like because most probably It won't work on different device sizes.

Anyone sees a better way to achieve the same result?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I had not intended the problem properly.

Comment: No problem :) .

Comment: You should rather consider making a view out of "Text: TextField" for username|password: input and put this in a VStack instead of having 2 separate VStacks of Text and TextField in a HStack.

Comment: @MartinM Yeah when I do that the textfields are not aligned on leading position. The X position for every textfield depends on the width of the Text on the left.

Comment: I think you are missing some thinking - I did too. Be flexible, and specify spacing value 8only when needed for layout. (That's not what I mean though.) A `View` is just a `struct`, not nearly the same as a `UIView`. Lay out everything you want - combine it into a *single* piece of UI via stacks (X, Y, or Z), and you have a single `View`. "It just works." Know that itt's centered both X and Y.  Now, give it modifiers for leading, or X or Y, of fonts, and framing, whatever.

Comment: @dfd Yeah I totally get thats it’s different than autolayouts. However I should be able to achieve what I want because from what I understood from the WWDC, this gonna replace storyboards sooner or later. And I think I should be able to achieve a simple login screen

Answer (score 10):

We're going to implement two new `View` modifier methods so that we can write this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var labelWidth: CGFloat? = nil
    @State var username = ""
    @State var password = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("User:")
                    .equalSizedLabel(width: labelWidth, alignment: .trailing)
                TextField("User", text: $username)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Password:")
                    .equalSizedLabel(width: labelWidth, alignment: .trailing)
                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        .storeMaxLabelWidth(in: $labelWidth)
    }
}
```

The two new modifiers are `equalSizedLabel(width:alignment:)` and `storeMaxLabelWidth(in:)`.

The `equalSizedLabel(width:alignment)` modifier does two things:

1. It applies the `width` and `alignment` to its content (the `Text(“User:”)` and `Text(“Password:”)` views).
2. It measures the width of its content and passes that up to any ancestor view that wants it.

The `storeMaxLabelWidth(in:)` modifier receives those widths measured by `equalSizedLabel` and stores the maximum width in the `$labelWidth` binding we pass to it.

So, how do we implement these modifiers? How do we pass a value from a descendant view up to an ancestor? In SwiftUI, we do this using the (currently undocumented) “preference” system.

To define a new preference, we define a type conforming to `PreferenceKey`. To conform to `PreferenceKey`, we have to define the default value for our preference, and we have to define how to combine the preferences of multiple subviews. We want our preference to be the maximum width of all the labels, so the default value is zero and we combine preferences by taking the maximum. Here's the `PreferenceKey` we'll use:

```swift
struct MaxLabelWidth: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = max(value, nextValue())
    }
}
```

The `preference` modifier function sets a preference, so we can say `.preference(key: MaxLabelWidth.self, value: width)` to set our preference, but we have to know what `width` to set. We need to use a `GeometryReader` to get the width, and it's a little tricky to do properly, so we'll wrap it up in a `ViewModifier` like this:

```swift
extension MaxLabelWidth: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content
            .background(GeometryReader { proxy in
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: Self.self, value: proxy.size.width)
            })
    }
}
```

What's happening above is we attach a background `View` to the content, because a background is always the same size as the content it's attached to. The background `View` is a `GeometryReader`, which (via the `proxy`) provides access to its own size. We have to give the `GeometryReader` its own content. Since we don't actually want to show a background behind the original content, we use `Color.clear` as the `GeometryReader`'s content. Finally, we use the `preference` modifier to store the width as the `MaxLabelWidth` preference.

Now have can define the `equalSizedLabel(width:alignment:)` and `storeMaxLabelWidth(in:)` modifier methods:

```swift
extension View {
    func equalSizedLabel(width: CGFloat?, alignment: Alignment) -> some View {
        return self
            .modifier(MaxLabelWidth())
            .frame(width: width, alignment: alignment)
    }
}

extension View {
    func storeMaxLabelWidth(in binding: Binding<CGFloat?>) -> some View {
        return self.onPreferenceChange(MaxLabelWidth.self) {
            binding.value = $0
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the result:

[image: result screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) You really added effort in it. This solution works but my problem with it is that we are duplicating the Texts. Which I think is definitely not the best way to do. Because now I have to bind data on both texts. And you know.. Duplication is never a good thing. But thank you for your solution :)

Comment: I've rewritten my answer using new information I learned about SwiftUI's preference system. This new answer doesn't have any duplication.

Comment: binding.value = $0 in your last extension is throwing warning "Generic parameter 'Subject' could not be inferred". Any suggestion?

Comment: @MatiasMasso - use `binding.wrappedValue = $0`. There's been an API change for `Binding` at some point.

Comment: Turns out this doesn't work on macOS. For some reason the widths of the resized labels collapse to 0. Interestingly, this affects the actually running view but not the preview. In the preview it looks fine.

Comment: My best guess is that on iOS the labels get a chance to have a non-zero width on initial layout, allowing their intrinsic sizes to reach the preferences. On macOS it seems like they start at zero and therefore their intrinsic size never comes into play.

One way I've found to work around it is to reduce prefs into an array and set width to the array's max value. That breaks the cycle of prefs seeing only 0 and clamping the width to 0.

Comment: Addendum: it does work on macOS if it's a plain `Text`. What doesn't work is if the `Text` is wrapped in a button.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Spacer`s alongside with `fixedSize` modifier for height. You should set set heights of any row's object in order to achieve exact `table style` view:

```
struct ContentView : View {

    private let height: Length = 32

    @State var username: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Login")
                .font(.title)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .lineLimit(nil)
            Text("Please")
                .font(.subheadline)

            HStack {
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Username: ") .frame(height: height)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Password: ") .frame(height: height)
                }
                VStack {
                    TextField($username, placeholder: Text("type something here..."))
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .frame(height: height)
                    Spacer()
                    TextField($username, placeholder: Text("type something here..."))
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .frame(height: height)
                }
                }
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

            }
            .padding()
    }
}
```

**Note that** setting height on `TextField` does not effect it's height directly, but it will just set the height of it's content text's height.

Comment: It's a cleaner solution and approach. However the the Texts are not centred in the middle of the textfields.

Comment: I made it more reliable. Check it out

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to do something similar with `Button`s on macOS, be advised that as of Xcode 11.3 you'll end up with the following at run time:

[image]

instead of:

[image]

I've written up my solution [in this blog post](https://finestructure.co/blog/2020/1/20/swiftui-equal-widths-view-constraints). It is quite similar to @rob-mayoff 's answer and works for both labels and buttons.