# How to align text fields by leading edges?

Tags: swiftui, layout

I've finally decided to bite the bullet and learn SwiftUI.

I'm rewriting a password generator program I wrote years ago (in Objective-C!) in SwiftUI.

I want my screen to contain labels and 2 text fields, where the text fields are left-aligned. (or, more precisely, leading edge alined.)

I have a `VStack` containing 2 `HStack`s, one for each text-field-plus-label.

I have successfully gotten the text fields to align by setting preceding text fields to use `.frame(minWidth: 175, alignment: .leading)`.

That works, but it is not ideal, since the `Text` will likely get longer when translated to other languages.

How would I get the text fields to align with each other? In UIKit and AutoLayout I would add a constraint setting the two text fields to have an equal leading edge.

Maybe a `VStack` containing to `HStack`s is not the way to go? I saw passing reference to something called `TableColumn`. Is there some Table object that would be better for this layout?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer().frame(width: 20)
                Text("Format String:")
                    .frame(minWidth: 175, alignment: .leading) // <- This is the hack
                TextField("%W.%w%d2", text: $formatString)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .frame(width: 120, height: 30)
                    .border(.gray)
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    print("Snork!")
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                }
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
                Spacer().frame(width: 20)
            }
            HStack {
                Spacer().frame(width: 20)
                Text("Number of passwords:")
                    .frame(minWidth: 175, alignment: .leading) // <- This is the hack
                TextField("20", value: $numPasswords, format: .number)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 30)
                    .border(.gray)
                Spacer() 
            }
```

That looks like this:

[image]

It looks like I want it to look, but it won't adapt if the text on the left gets longer.

Comment: LabeledContent is likely what you want but a LazyVGrid or LazyHGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of plain `Text` labels, you can use a `ZStack` to find the width needed by both labels. Inside each `ZStack`, one label is visible, the other is hidden.

If you are using an `HStack` with spacing between items (which is what you are doing in your example) then I would also suggest you use `.leading` or `.trailing` padding instead of a `Spacer` with a fixed width. This is because, the `HStack` will add spacing between the `Spacer` and the next item, which means the space you get may not be what you are expecting.

Here is the same example with these changes applied:

```swift
VStack {
    HStack {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Format String:")
            Text("Number of passwords:").hidden()
        }
        .padding(.leading, 20)
        TextField("%W.%w%d2", text: $formatString)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .frame(width: 120, height: 30)
            .border(.gray)
        Spacer()
        Button {
            print("Snork!")
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "info.circle")
        }
        .foregroundStyle(.tint)
        .padding(.trailing, 20)
    }
    HStack {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Format String:").hidden()
            Text("Number of passwords:")
        }
        .padding(.leading, 20)
        TextField("20", value: $numPasswords, format: .number)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 30)
            .border(.gray)
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

[image: JustifiedLabels]

Answer (score 0):

If your deployment target is at least iOS 16, the best way to do this is by using [`Grid`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/grid):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var formatString = ""
    @State var numPasswords = 20

    var body: some View {
        Grid(alignment: .leadingFirstTextBaseline) {
            GridRow {
                Text("Format String:")
                    .gridColumnAlignment(.trailing)
                TextField("%W.%w%d2", text: $formatString)
                    .frame(width: 120)
                Button {
                    print("Snork!")
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                }
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            }
            GridRow {
                Text("Number of passwords:")
                    .gridColumnAlignment(.trailing)
                TextField("20", value: $numPasswords, format: .number)
                    .frame(width: 50)
            }
        }
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
    }
}
```

If your deployment target is older than iOS 16, you can use [Benzy Neez's hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77061926/77567), or you can implement a more complex but more general solution like I outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56673501/77567).